# easiest way to mix page content with template functionality in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Im wondering is it possible to mix page content that the user can edit in wordpress with template functionality. 
At the moment it seems I have to decide where `the_content` is going to go in my template and thats where ALL the users content goes.

But what if I want for example 
some user content, then my own functionality from a template, then some more content the user can add in the page, then more functionality

Here is an example, the text highlighted in blue above the 4 boxes at the bottom is functionality. But ideally, I would like the user to be able to also change the 4 boxes through wordpress. But I was forced to hardcode those as Im already using `the_content` above that.
http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/academy/

There are more complex examples too, thast just a simple one
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) to run custom code and custom loops, and those four boxes fall perfectly into [Widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets) sections. Alternatively you can use [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to basically make anything possible in your page templates. However, it's quite difficult to make a sexy drag-and-drop content builder interface that does not suck. But doable. :)

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but the thing is im using page templates already, what im looking to do moreso is figure out a way of being able to sort of swap back and forth between user content and page template funcionality. Perhaps Ill have to look into custom fields, but I already have alot of them there, and dont want the whole page being plasted with them. Cheers